# Wrap array in an array in JSONata

Tags: jsonata

Lets say I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
{ a: [ 1, 2, 3] }
```

I want to return 'a' wrapped in an array:

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3] ]
```

Is there any way to do this in JSONata?

Intuitively you would try `[a]`, which you would expect to return the array as `[[1,2,3]]`, but this returns `[1,2,3]`, because of array singleton equivalence in JSONata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below query

```
[[a]] - wrapping a within 2 set of square brackets
```

Since 'a' returns

```
 1, 2, 3
```

`[[a]]` returns

```
[[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried this. I edited my question to stress this point. It doesn't work because of array singleton equivalence will cause the wrapping array to be removed.

Comment: Hmm.. DIdn't you write `[a]` in your answer initially? That is what I tried. I see `[[a]]` does indeed work as expected. Rather unintuitive though. Can you make a minor edit to your reply, so I can change the vote and accept? Sorry for the confusion.